# Flowground REST-API: Difference between the flow properties status and current_status

Tags: flowground

The flow data that can be loaded via the REST API (https://api.flowground.net/docs/v2/#retrieve-a-flow-by-id) contains the properties `data.attributes.status` and `data.attributes.current_status`. In my case both have the value `"active"`. What is the difference between these two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.attributes.status` this can be active and inactive. This is basically how we want a flow to be.

`data.attributes.current_status` shows the status as is.

For example:

You have an active flow. It has both `data.attributes.status` & `data.attributes.current_status` as active.

Then you stop the flow and for some period of time (while the pods still running and then shuts down), it will show `data.attributes.status` as inactive and `data.attributes.current_status` - active.
​
After Admiral does it's job, the status changes to inactive on both `data.attributes.status` & `data.attributes.current_status`.